# Why AWS API Gateway response size larger much than S3 object's size

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS API Gateway to integrate S3.

I know the limit of request, response of API Gateway is 10 MB.
However, when I request a 8 MB video , the error show:

> Response body of size 15552415 exceeds maximum of 10485760 bytes and
> streaming mode not supported.

[image]

I wonder how the response body can be larger much than the video's size. I expect the response size same as video's size. I tried with 3MB, 7MB video, browser have downloaded successfully and downloaded video's size same as original size (3, 7 MB).

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, that looks like some configuration, design of API Gateway cause the issue.
To download large file, we can use range download by setup HTTP response 206 follow:
[image]